# How to freeze certain layers in models obtained from keras.applications

Tags: keras, transfer-learning, finetuning

I am currrently trainning to use transfer learning on ResNet152 obtained from Keras Applications:

```
tf.keras.applications.ResNet152(
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(400,250,3)
)
```

I know to freeze all the layers I need to set the  `trainable` attribute to `False`, but right now I need to freeze certain layers. More specifically, I need to unfreeze the last three layers of this model but freeze the rest. So how do I do that?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61552605/13546426) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46625395/13546426) answer.

Comment: Its a crude way, but use model.summary() you get all independent names. Then you can train  / freeze depends on the layer names. everyname is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can freeze all the layer with `model.trainable = False` and unfreeze the last three layers with :

```
for layer in model.layers[-3:]:
    layer.trainable = True
```

the `model.layers` contain a list of all the ordered layer that compose the model.